# Posrgres 13.1: Slow execution of sql query with inner select or join

Tags: database, postgresql, query-optimization, database-performance

I have a database with ~2.5M persons and ~3M pets. Each pet belongs to a person.
There are 32'300 cats (`kind = 3`) in the database.
Is there a way to speed up the following statement?

```sql
SELECT p.name 
FROM person p
WHERE p.id IN (
    SELECT pet.person_id
    FROM pet pet
    WHERE pet.kind = 3 -- cat
)
```

The execution plan is as follows:

```sql
Nested Loop  (cost=898.14..66545.89 rows=32005 width=37) (actual time=22.546..12407.109 rows=32300 loops=1)
  Output: p.name
  Inner Unique: true
  Buffers: shared hit=85815 read=43622
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=897.71..1218.20 rows=32049 width=8) (actual time=21.702..42.032 rows=32300 loops=1)
        Output: pet.person_id
        Group Key: pet.person_id
        Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 3089kB
        Buffers: shared hit=2 read=235
        ->  Index Only Scan using petx1 on pet pet  (cost=0.43..817.59 rows=32049 width=8) (actual time=1.085..10.478 rows=32300 loops=1)
              Output: pet.kind, pet.person_id
              Index Cond: (pet.kind = '3'::bigint)
              Heap Fetches: 2
              Buffers: shared hit=2 read=235
  ->  Index Scan using personxpk on person p  (cost=0.43..2.06 rows=1 width=45) (actual time=0.382..0.382 rows=1 loops=32300)
        Output: p.name, p.id
        Index Cond: (p.id = pet.person_id)
        Buffers: shared hit=85813 read=43387
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=444 read=64
Planning Time: 26.404 ms
Execution Time: 12413.696 ms
```

I already have the following indexes.
I don't have an index for the person's name because I need to select more attributes later from the person and an index for each attribute seems excessive.

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX personxpk ON person USING btree (person_id)
CREATE INDEX petx1 ON pet USING btree (kind, person_id)
```

I already tried to rewrite the SQL as follows.
This doubles the execution speed (probably because of the two parallel workers), but it is still not the desired speed.

```sql
SELECT p.name
FROM person p
JOIN pet pet ON pet.person_id = p.id AND pet.kind = 3 -- cat
```

Here the execution plan for this statement:

```sql
Gather  (cost=1000.86..32294.58 rows=32005 width=37) (actual time=2.663..4303.776 rows=32300 loops=1)
  Output: p.name
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  Buffers: shared hit=85819 read=43622
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.86..28094.08 rows=13335 width=37) (actual time=1.850..4272.721 rows=10767 loops=3)
        Output: p.name
        Inner Unique: true
        Buffers: shared hit=85819 read=43622
        Worker 0:  actual time=1.787..4274.702 rows=10780 loops=1
          Buffers: shared hit=28696 read=14503
        Worker 1:  actual time=1.734..4271.052 rows=10780 loops=1
          Buffers: shared hit=28598 read=14602
        ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using petx1 on pet pet  (cost=0.43..630.63 rows=13354 width=8) (actual time=0.946..8.839 rows=10767 loops=3)
              Output: pet.kind, pet.person_id
              Index Cond: (pet.kind = '3'::bigint)
              Heap Fetches: 2
              Buffers: shared hit=4 read=235
              Worker 0:  actual time=0.966..8.497 rows=10780 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=1 read=77
              Worker 1:  actual time=0.831..9.440 rows=10780 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=1 read=78
        ->  Index Scan using personxpk on person p  (cost=0.43..2.06 rows=1 width=45) (actual time=0.395..0.395 rows=1 loops=32300)
              Output: p.name, p.id
              Index Cond: (p.id = pet.person_id)
              Buffers: shared hit=85815 read=43387
              Worker 0:  actual time=0.394..0.394 rows=1 loops=10780
                Buffers: shared hit=28695 read=14426
              Worker 1:  actual time=0.394..0.394 rows=1 loops=10780
                Buffers: shared hit=28597 read=14524
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=450 read=58
Planning Time: 27.957 ms
Execution Time: 6307.435 ms
```

Comment: This index could work better, result in an index only scan on the table "pet": CREATE UNIQUE INDEX petxpk2 ON pet USING btree (kind,person_id);

Comment: It does result in an index only scan for pet which performs a bit better. (~5s faster).
The main problem seems to be the loop on the index scan using personxpk.

Comment: Could you please share the result from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for your SQL statements? That gives you a bit more information about what is going on. Rewriting the query to use WHERE EXISTS might also help, could be (slightly?) faster

Comment: Your second plan says `Bitmap Index Scan on petx2`. Is that supposed to be `petxpk2` or is there another index you haven't told us about? PLease [edit] your question.

Comment: That sould be petx1. I renamed the index. I also added the EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for the first statement.

Comment: Only 1% of pets are cats?  That seems rather unlikely.   And do you really need to efficiently make a list of everyone who owns a cat?  If you are going to mail everyone a coupon for cat food, 12 seconds doesn't seem like much of a burden.

Comment: "I don't have an index for the person's name because I need to select more attributes later from the person"  Then you are asking for help to optimize the wrong thing.  What is the point of optimizing something you already know is wrong to start with?

Answer (score 1):

Some observations:

1. This is a bulk data query. It's designed to retrieve tens of thousands of rows in its result set. Bulk data handling takes some time even with the most efficient of queries. Your client program, the one issuing the query, must ingest all those rows and do something with them.
2. You used a [covering index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) `(kind, person_id)` on your `pet` table to good effect.
3. You could try a similar covering index on your `person` table.

   ```sql
   CREATE INDEX id_name ON person USING BTREE (id, name);
   ```

   This might help your query time a bit, because it can be satisfied directly from the index. But see my first observation.
4. Why did you make these two indexes unique? This question comes from a guy with two (very lazy) cats. But your indexes say I may only have one.

   ```sql
   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX petxpk ON pet USING BTREE (person_id, kind)
   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX petxpk2 ON pet USING BTREE (kind, person_id)
   ```
5. The second of these two indexes is made redundant by the first one.

   ```sql
   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX petxpk2 ON pet USING BTREE (kind, person_id)
   CREATE INDEX petx1 ON pet USING BTREE (kind)
   ```

Comment: I agree, this is a bulk query and might be already as efficient as possible. Based on the answer of @frank-heikens I added the covering index `(kind, person_id)`, which made the `petx1` index redundat. You're right the `UNIQUE`  is wrong here :). Thank you!